# LINQ - Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use

Tags: wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table `Unit` with two columns `UnitName` n `UnitDescription`.`UnitName` is the primary key n I have added a unique name constraint on `UnitName`.
Now when I add data using linq through my application it catches a `duplicate key exception` if I add a duplicate unit name and does not add data in database but thereafter even if add a unique unit name it still catches that `duplicate key exception` and gives me a message dialog box about that `name existing` but it adds data in database.Why is it happening so ?

```
DemoDataContext DC = new DemoDataContext();

ObservableUnit Ob_unit;

private void btn_save_unit()
{
    try
    {
         tbl_unit unit = new tbl_unit();
         unit.unitname = txt_unit name.Text();
         DC.tbl_unit.InsertOnSubmit(unit);
         Ob_unit.Add(unit);
         DC.SubmitChanges();
     }
      catch(DuplicateKeyException)
      {
          Message.Show(message);
      }
 }

 class ObservableUnit : ObservableCollection<tbl_unit>
 {
     public ObservableUnit(DemoDataContext DDC)
     {
           foreach (tbl_unit thisUnit in DDC.tbl_units)
           {
                 this.Add(thisUnit);
            }
      }
}
```

`DC` is `DataContext` automatically created by linq and `Ob_unit` is `ObservableCollection` Of `tbl_Unit` and both are globally declared

Plz tell me how to solve it .Thank you

Comment: Do you have a `[Key]` attribute on your primary key column?

Comment: UnitName varchar(50) not null primary key.This is how I have created unit name.

Comment: Did you create a new context or are you still trying to save with the old context - which contains the original double entity? Contexts should *not* live any longer than necessary. If they do, you should make sure you remove failed entities from them. Remove the old entity from the context in the exception handler

Comment: Old one only .k wait let me try changing it

Comment: Thnkx it works fine.thank u panagiotis